# If statement doesn't work with a matrix condition

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. My if statement doesn't work with a condition involving matrices.

This is my input:

```
i = matrix(c(1,0,0,1),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
j = matrix(c(1,0,0,2),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
if(i%*%i == j){
  print("yes")
}
```

This is my output:

```
> i = matrix(c(1,0,0,1),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
> j = matrix(c(1,0,0,2),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
> if(i%*%i == j){
+   print("yes")
+ }
[1] "yes"
Warning message:
In if (i %*% i == j) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Nothing, since i%*%i != j

and also no error

Comment: As the message (warning, not an error) says, only the first element is compared.  Try `(i%*%i)[1] == j[1]` to see why.  Perhaps you mean `if(all(i%*%i == j))`.  Or perhaps `if(identical(i%*%i, j))`

Comment: Yup that's what I was looking for, thanks :)